# how to organise common preamble of dtx files

Tags: package-writing, preamble, dtx

I have some new packages (see [latexthesistemplate/trunk/packages/template](http://code.google.com/p/latexthesistemplate/source/browse/#svn/trunk/packages/template)

which all use a shared preamble file. I want all of them to have the same packages and commands available and the same layout. These packages shall be uploaded to ctan as soon
as the documentation is final.

I could place these [preamble files](http://code.google.com/p/latexthesistemplate/source/browse/#svn/trunk/packages/template/preamble) in every dtx file, but that would be only extra work. Or I could create a new class file just for my own package documentation.

However we have so many non-documented package documentation classes that I do not want to add one. Especially since miss a lot of functionality in the standard documentation class.

Is there any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be only three files, so I'd just include them in each dtx file, it isn't so much extra considering all the rest of the documentation overhead.

However If you do want a special class file for this, to pick up on your comment about lacking functionality from the standard class, there is no need to lose functionality.
Just make a `mydoc.cls` that looks like

```
\ProvidesClass{mydoc}
\LoadClassWithOptions{ltxdoc}
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
...
\input{file-n}
```

Then your class will have all the same functionality and options as `ltxdoc`

Comment: I use a related but different approach. All inputs are replaced in a perl script by the code. Thus the code for published packages does not depend on further files. And most common code is placed in a separate package file (currently named doctools.sty).